# SLComposeViewController returning null (ShareKit)

Tags: objective-c, sharekit, slcomposeviewcontroller

My SLComposeViewController is returning null whenever I try to call composeViewControllerForServiceType:serviceType on it.
I can allocate it like:

```
SLComposeViewController *test = [[SLComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

and I'll get

```
<SLComposeViewController: 0x1e057180>
```

if I log it.
but if I do:

```
SLComposeViewController *test2 = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:serviceType];
```

It returns `nil` (with serviceType being com.apple.social.facebook).

I have no idea what's going on. Anyone experienced this or know what could be going on?

**Added:**
I'm in a country (and bought my ipad here) where FB & Twitter are not accessible. This problem only occurs for these two services, if I do SLServiceTypeSinaWeibo it works. Interesting to note also that it doesn't work even if I have a VPN running.

Comment: `nil` means that some error occurred. `serviceType` should be `SLServiceTypeFacebook`, have you tried with that?

Comment: Yeah tried it, no difference.